Find and extract a number from a success Message
I'm facing difficulty retrieving a specific text pattern from an HTML element in my webpage. Here's the HTML snippet:
This is from my website and I want to retrieve from "
Work Order 0000037282 has been reissued.

only :
x =0000037282

Save it and use it later in another page something like workordernumber = x . Each time x will be a different number.
This is what i have in front end :
<div class="row ng-scope" ng-if="successMessages.length">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <!-- ngRepeat: success in successMessages track by $index -->
            <div class="row ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="success in successMessages track by $index" ng-bind="success.message">Invoice 0000026791 has been credited. Credit document HO0000000033 was created.</div>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: success in successMessages track by $index -->
            <div class="row ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="success in successMessages track by $index" ng-bind="success.message">Work Order 0000037282 has been reissued.</div>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: success in successMessages track by $index -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

Second message , which i need , it's Work Order 0000037282 has been reissued.
this is from my test
await reissueWorkOrderConfirmationModal.ConfirmAsync();

string? workOrderNumber = await creditInvoiceModal.GetReissuedWorkOrderNumberAsync();

if (workOrderNumber != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Reissued Work Order Number: {workOrderNumber}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to retrieve the reissued work order number.");
}

And this is what i added in the modal :
public async Task<string?> GetReissuedWorkOrderNumberAsync()
{
    // Execute JavaScript in the browser context to retrieve the text of the success message elements
    string successMessages = await _page.EvaluateAsync<string>(@"() => {
        const messages = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.alert.alert-success .row.ng-binding.ng-scope'));
        return messages.map(message => message.innerText).join('|');
    }");
    // Define the regular expression pattern to match the Work Order number
    string pattern = @"Work Order (\d+) has been reissued.";
    // Use regular expression to match the pattern
    Match match = Regex.Match(successMessages, pattern);
    // Check if the pattern is found
    if (match.Success)
    {
        // Extract the Work Order number from the matched groups
        string workOrderNumber = match.Groups[1].Value;
        return workOrderNumber;
    }
    // Return null if the pattern is not found
    return null;
}


There are a lot of easier ways to do this than using a regular expression..

Also, you haven’t explained what your actual problem is?

Where is your code failing?

By the way, that's a string, nit a number. If you do most (not all) number-y things on "0000037282", you'll find that the leading zeros will go away

Why do think you need to scrape this from your page? It must have been a variable before it was put into that string, so have it stored somewhere accessible.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Adymus you could use the locator upto that element  using xpath and following-sibling and then gettext and then use regular expression to get that number
